# Create multiple space separated files using touch with curly brace extension

Tags: command-line, bash

If I do this:

```
touch {1,2,3}.txt
```

I get

```
1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
```

But if I do this

```
touch {"File 1", "File 2"}.txt
```

I don't get expected `'File 1.txt' 'File 2.txt'`. What is the proper approach in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whitespace after the `,` causes the shell to parse your expression as two separate tokens, instead of as a brace expansion:

```
$ printf '%s\n' {"File 1", "File 2"}.txt
{File 1,
File 2}.txt
```

You just need to remove the whitespace:

```
$ printf '%s\n' {"File 1","File 2"}.txt
File 1.txt
File 2.txt
```

So

```
$ touch {"File 1","File 2"}.txt
$ ls
'File 1.txt'  'File 2.txt'
```

More compactly, you could also use `touch "File "{1,2}.txt` or `touch File\ {1,2}.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, also in bash, this can be done in a **for loop** like so:

```
for f in "fil 1" "file 2"; do
    touch "$f".txt
done
```